# MLA in-text Citations with no author, as well as same title?

Tags: citations, mla

In MLA, how do I write in-text citations that have no author, as well as a same title with another source in my bibliography?

For example, I have these 2 sources:

> "Alternative Energy." Discover 28.1 (2007): 20. Middle Search Plus. Web. 29 Mar. 2015.

and

> "Alternative Energy." - Wind, Solar, Hydro and Other Alt Energy Sources for Home Power. Web. 30 Mar. 2015. http://www.altenergy.org/.

I know that you would first try the author's last name like (Stewart), but there isn't any, and then you try the title ("Alternative Energy"), but in this case they are both the same. How can I in-text cite this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, the standard way to separate two citations like this would be to include the year in the citation. EG: "This is quote one" ("Alternative Energy" 2007), and "this is quote two" ("Alternative Energy" 2015). I cannot cite a source for this, though, as I have not used MLA in years and do not have a copy of the handbook available.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you may have to remove the dash before the word "Wind" in your second entry. As for the in-text citation, the first one will be cited as ("Alternative Energy," *Discover*) and the second as ("Alternative Energy," *Wind*). This issue has been addressed in MLA 7th edition, section 6.4.4 (Page number in my edition is 223).

Answer (score 1):

I hate to just answer with links, but this resource is invaluable:

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/01/

Comment: I've read that a several other sources already. It does say that if it is the same author, then put a shortened title of the work. Nowhere does it say what to do if the shortened titles of the work are the exact same, however. That's probably because it's an extremely rare case, but I have come across it.

Answer (score 0):

The Purdue OWL is a great resource for MLA formatting and citations. Here's a link to the page on the basics of in-text citations:

[The Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/)

Comment: I've read that a several other sources already. It does say that if it is the same author, then put a shortened title of the work. Nowhere does it say what to do if the shortened titles of the work are the exact same, however. That's probably because it's an extremely rare case, but I have come across it.